# Manifold_Lie algebra compatibility

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

In this  question we try to improve  some parts of [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209694/differential-and-pre-differential-of-jacobi-identity) as follows:

> What is  an example  of  a  manifold $M$ and  a  Lie  algebra $L$ (with the same  dimension) such that $M$ **does not** admit  an smooth  $(1,2)$  tensor $\alpha$ which  satisfies  the Jacobi identity at each fibre $T_x(M)$ and the fibrewise Lie algebra structure  $\alpha_x$ on $T_x (M)$ is isomorphic to $L$?

What type of obstructions would appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple example is to let $M=S^2$ and let $L$ be the nonabelian Lie algebra of dimension $2$.  If such an $\alpha$ existed, its range would be a rank-1 subbundle $L\subset TS^2$, but this cannot exist for topological reasons.

The general obstruction is whether the manifold $M$ admits an $\mathrm{Aut}(L)$-structure, and this can be determined by homotopy-theoretical methods.

Another good example is to take $M=S^4$ and $L$ any nonabelian Lie algebra of dimension~$4$.  Since $\mathrm{Aut}(L)$ always preserves a nontrivial subalgebra of $L$ in this case, such a structure $\alpha$ on $M$ would induce a nontrivial subbundle of $TS^4$, and this does not exist, so $\alpha$ cannot exist.

Comment: Fibrewise the range is a subvector space of tangent space. But why is it a subbundle?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does the question automatically imply that "We have  a Bundle of Lie algebras"?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is smooth, then, for any linearly independent vector fields $X$ and $Y$, $\alpha(X,Y)$ will be a smooth nonvanishing vector field that takes values in the subspace  at each point, so the range will be a smooth subbundle.  For your second comments question, the answer is 'yes'.

Comment: I am sorry if my question is elementary: Is it obvious that the conditions in  my initial question automatically implies that the structure group can be reduced to Aut(L)?

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  Yes, it is obvious:  If such an $\alpha$ exists, let $F\to M$ be the bundle of coframes (i.e., linear isomorphisms) $u:T_xM\to L$ that are isomorphisms of $(T_xM,\alpha_x)$ with $(L,[,])$ as Lie algebras.  Then $F\to M$ is a reduction of the $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ coframe bundle to a principal right $\mathrm{Aut}(L)$-subbundle.